# circuit,draw(output='mpl')でエラー

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud

Windows10のアナコンダでのジュピターノートを利用しています。
circuit.draw(output='mpl')が使えなくなり困っています。
エラーがでます。
circuit.draw(output='text')はつかえます。
また、普通にplt.plot(...)は使えます。

しかたなく、アナコンダとQiskitを再インスしましたが
だめです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 念のために確認しますが、`pylatexenc` モジュールはインストールしましたか？ これは `mpl` で描画する場合でも必要となるモジュールです。

Comment: どのようなエラーが出ているのか、エラーメッセージを質問文にペーストしてください。また、[ibm-cloud] タグがついていますがどのように関係しますでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu IBM のクラウドサービスの一つに [IBM Quantum Experience](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/) があって、Q Experience を利用するための(それだけではありませんが) SDK として [Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/) が提供されています(オープンソース)。